# java script variable in html tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have been using a Conveyor belt slideshow script from www.dynamicdrive.com. I want to make the height of of the image a variable value. heres the code.

```
var _docHeight = (document.height !== undefined) ? document.height : document.body.offsetHeight;
var _docWidth = (document.width !== undefined) ? document.width : document.body.offsetWidth;
var h;

var w1 = window.innerWidth;
var h1 = window.innerHeight;
var w = w1/1.365;
var h = h1 /1;
//Specify the slider's width (in pixels)
//Specify the slider's width (in pixels)
var sliderwidth=w + "px"
//Specify the slider's height
var sliderheight=h + "px"
//Specify the slider's slide speed (larger is faster 1-10)
var slidespeed=2
//configure background color:
slidebgcolor="#000000"
var h3 = 20;

//Specify the slider's images
var leftrightslide=new Array()
var finalslide='2'
leftrightslide[0]='<img src="0price.png" height="h" border=0></a>'
```

please help

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? leftrightslide[0]='<img src="0price.png" height="' + h + '" border=0></a>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got yourself a syntax error - you're not putting the variable into your string correctly. Try this instead:

```
leftrightslide[0]='<img src="0price.png" height="'+h+'" border=0></a>';
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Feel free to upvote/accept if the answer helped you :)

Comment: i dont have enough reputation but as soon as i do i will

Comment: You can always accept the answer, on your own question. Click the tick beside the answer.